# Automatically Show (Un-hide) Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a method whereby columns in Excel (2003, 2007 and/or 2010) can be automatically shown (un-hidden) when the column to the left contains data?

Something like this:

```
IF column to the left contains data
THEN show column


+-----+-----+  
|  C  |  C  |     //If column1 contains data
|  O  |  O  |     //Then reveal/show (unhide) column2
|  L  |  L  |
|  U  |  U  |
|  M  |  M  |
|  N  |  N  |
|  1  |  2  |
+-----+-----+
```

I'm guessing that VB code is required but am unsure as to what this would be.

Further to this, is there a way to automatically show the column going by the date (first day of each month)?  This is a little more complicated.  For example:

```
FOR all dates
    IF system date = year(month.day1)  //If it is the first day of a new month
        THEN show column(month)  //Then show the corresponding column for that month
    ENDIF
ENDFOR

i.e. IF system date = 01/09/2012
     THEN show column(September)
```

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you ok with a VBA code to do this? Also does the first part of the question applies only to column 1 and column 2?

Comment: Hello.  VBA code should be fine, yes.  Also, it would apply to all columns in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, you need VBA to achieve that. Use the Worksheet_Change event which fires whenever something changes. Then, use one of the various methods to determine if a column is not empty (http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2006/03/determine_if_a_.html, or just google). Alternatively, if this is to slow because if fires almost all the time, you could use the Worksheet_Activate() event (an overview of all Excel events can be found [here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/event.htm#change)).

If your column 7 contains data, you can unhide column 8 using MyWorksheet.Columns("8:8").Hidden = False.

Your second problem can be solved in a similar way. In the Worksheet_Activate(), check if today is the first day in a month using Day(Date) = 1 (I guess it needs to take into account that the user may not be using Excel this day, so the code should be a little more complex) and show that column using MyWorksheet.Columns("12:12").Hidden = False (or whichever it is) for December 1st.

All this code assumes that the columns are already there, just hidden.